# How to enable/use cross-origin resource sharing with MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to submit a form using AJAX to a MVC 3 Controller.

The form and the controller are on two different domains, which is why i want to use CORS.

I have read that the following code should do the trick in ASP.NET:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

from http://enable-cors.org/#how-asp.net

Should this code go directly in the controller that takes the form data?
As far as i know, there has to be some exchange of data between the client posting data and the server, to determine wether CORS is enabled/supported or not, so i figure that the one line of code has to go somewhere else?

Thanks

Comment: I've built an spec-compliant open source CORS implementation that you can read about here: http://brockallen.com/2012/06/28/cors-support-in-webapi-mvc-and-iis-with-thinktecture-identitymodel/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could go in the controller. Actually I would probably externalize it in a custom action filter to avoid repeating it in every controller action that needs to be invoked from a cross domain AJAX call. There are no additional steps necessary. Just make sure that your browser supports CORS because if it doesn't adding this line will have strictly no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When i add the headers to the controller, can i then use a normal ajax POST on the client, or do i have to specify something specific for it to work?

Comment: No, you don't need to specify anything in particular. It should work with a standard `$.post()` if the browser that you are using supports CORS.

Comment: I need to use it for an ipad2 application, so im hoping that a new out-of-the-box ipad2 supports it. http://caniuse.com/cors :)

Comment: Yeah, looks like iOS Safari supports it.